# Is there a good package for by-hand / manual / judgmental factor / component rotation?

Tags: r, pca, rotational-matrices, psych

I'm trying to add a function to *manually* (or *by-hand*, or *judgmentally*) **rotate** a factor loadings matrix from principal components analysis to the [`qmethod`](https://github.com/aiorazabala/qmethod) R package.
By-hand rotation as in: one specifies the angle by which to rotate any given pair of factors.
(Yeah it's weird, but it makes sense in [Q Methodology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_methodology).)

For now, I'm *not* looking for an interactive GUI (though that'd be real nice), but just a CLI interface where you press `left` or `right` and get updated plots and finally say `OK`.

The baseline is something like this from the legacy [PQMethod](http://schmolck.userweb.mwn.de/qmethod/downpqwin.htm) program.
[image]
Here's [a short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7W3DDUVD3s).

My current approach is to use `psych::factor.rotate()`, and to program a somewhat interactive (as in `right`, `left`, `OK`) CLI interface on top of that with updating plots.

Still, I wonder whether *someone hasn't done this already*.

I googled away, but came up short (couldn't even find a by-hand rotation procedure other than `psych::factor.rotate()`.

Any suggestions?

Ps.: bonus if you have a suggestion for how to do this with an interactive GUI.

Pps.: anyone kind enough to add a `qmethod` tag to this? I don't have the necessary points.

Comment: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow..."_

Comment: @zero323 uh, really? Hope it's acceptable.
In my defense, I *have* shown the steps I already took: *"Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*
Also, I don't think this will cause deluge of opinionated posts ("use this!", "use that!") – it's more a question of whether there *is* a package out there, and I'm just not using the right keyword or frame to find it.

Anyway, thanks for policing – I know that's what keeps this site so great.

Comment: @maxheld try if http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com is the place to ask, check their help center if it allows this question

Comment: I am not sure but may be you are looking for manipulate package?

Comment: @maxheld Well,  personally  I have mixed feelings about it. While asking for a recommendation is off-topic, recommendation as an answer is not. At the end of the day it is probably more about the way how you formulate the question than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd give `manipulate` a try - something in the veins of:

```
library(psych)
library(manipulate)
l <- l_orig <- unclass(loadings(principal(Harman.5, 2, scores=TRUE)))
manipulate( 
  { 
    if(rotateRight) 
      l <<- factor.rotate(l, angle, 1, 2)
    if (rotateLeft)
      l <<- factor.rotate(l, -1*angle, 1, 2)

    plot(l, xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1), xlab = 1, ylab = 2); abline(v = 0); abline(h = 0)
  }, 
  angle = slider(1, 90, step=1, initial = 1, label = "Angle"), 
  rotateRight = button(">"),
  rotateLeft = button("<")
)
l; l_orig
```

[image]

Comment: wow fantastic @lukeA – I'll definitely add that.
Only downside: works only in RStudio, correct?

Comment: yep, `manipulate` [provides](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/manipulate/manipulate.pdf) _"Interactive plotting functions for use within RStudio"_